# put navigation inside content div

Tags: html, css

I am seeking help from you to correct this webpage.
If you look at the html and css posted below, you there are following unintended behavior:
1) the galnavigation seats over the content. what I really want is:(if I consider the box as my webpage)

```
|-----------------------------------------|
|<h2>My Gallery</h2>                      |
|Here is some collection of.....          |
|<gal_navigation>                         |
|                                         |
|href Garchumuk    href Falta             |
|  img src           img src              |
|    of                 of                |
|  Garchumuk           Falta              |
|           and so on                     |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

2) also, as shown, href should appear at the top of the img, not beside.

It will be best, if this can be done browser independent way. (currently, the href appears at the top of img in firefox, but not in gnome's epiphany)

the codes as far as I have managed:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MySite</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css" media="all">


    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
    <h1>
      My Site
    </h1>
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="gal_content">
    <!--<p>-->
    <!--<img src="images/gallery.jpg" alt="MyPic">-->
    <!--</p>-->
    <h2>
      My Gallery 
    </h2>
    Here is some collection of pictures I have taken during several trips. These galleries are hosted in Picasa and Flickr web album.
    <div id="galnavigation">
      <table style="width:94px;margin:0.5em 0 0em 0;" border="0px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
          <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/bnrj.rudra/Garchumuk?feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"> <font style="color:#fff;font-size:.75em; text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Garchumuk</i></font><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7eOvmJb2ASM/R4D-sw0h7YE/AAAAAAAABqw/mR4XSrT2VNM/s160-c/Garchumuk.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 0px;" alt="garchumuk"></a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
          <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/bnrj.rudra/FaltaTrip?feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"><font style="color:#fff; font-size:.75em;text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Falta</i></font><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3zQd1oQRUA0/TRgv6Z4AJ8E/AAAAAAAAD-s/Uq2lqhTw_Zo/s160-c/FaltaTrip.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 0px;" alt="falta"></a>
        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/106471678921553351367/TakiTrip?authuser=0&feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"><font style="color:#fff;font-size:.75em; text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Taki Trip</i></font><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EKTODai7XAs/SXtHhvE6v9E/AAAAAAAAEz8/PCCXLZKBLM4/s160-c/TakiTrip.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 4px;"></a>
        </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footermainPan">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    font : 100% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color : #0a8bf8;
    background : #184470;
    margin : 0;
      }
h1 {
    position : absolute;
    height : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
      }
.accessaid2, h1 {
    position : absolute;
    height : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
      }
.accessaid, h1 {
    position : absolute;
    height : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
      }
#header {
    background : #184470 url(images/banner2.png) no-repeat;
    height : 60px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    border-left : 214px solid #184470;
      }
#navigation {
    position : absolute;
    top : 60px;
    left : 1%;
    width : 15%;
    color : #e4ecef;
    font-size : 110%;
      }
#navigation ul {
    margin : 0 0 2em 0;
    padding : 0;
    list-style : none;
    color : #e4ecef;
      }
#navigation ul a {
    color : white;
    text-decoration : none;
    display : block;
    background : #4674b2;
    padding : 0 0.5em;
    margin : 0 2em 1px 1em;
    color : #e4ecef;
    box-shadow :0 10px 10px #000;
      }
#navigation a:visited {
    color : #e4ecef;
      }
#navigation a:hover {
    background : #5096f0;
      }
#content {
        background : #e4ecef;
        padding : 0.0em 2.5em;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        --moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        width : 62%;
        float : right;
        margin-right : 17%;
        margin-left : 30%;
        border : 0px;
        background : #e0e9f8;
      }
#gal_content {
        background : #e4ecef;
        padding : 0.0em 2.5em;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        --moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        width : 62%;
        float : right;
        margin-right : 17%;
        margin-left : 30%;
        border : 0px;
        /*background : #e0e9f8;*/
      }
#galnavigation {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 23%;
    width : 17%;
    color : #000;
    font-size : 100%;
      }
#galnavigation a:hover {
    background : #5096f0;
      }
#galnavigation ul {
    margin : 100% 0 1em 0;
    padding : 0;
    list-style : none;
    color : #000;
      }
#galnavigation ul a {
    color : white;
    text-decoration : none;
    display : block;
    background : #4674b2;
    padding : 0 0.5em;
    margin : 0 1em 1px 1em;
    color : #e4ecef;
    box-shadow : 0 10px 10px #000;
      }

h2 {
        font-size : 200%;
        color : #184470;
      }
h3 {
        font-size : 125%;
        color : #184470;
      }
#container {
/*position : relative;
width : 100%;
border : solid #036;
border-width : 0 0px;
margin : auto;*/
}
#content img {
        height : 200px;
        padding : 0;
        border : 0 solid #333;
        float : right;
        margin : .5em 0em 2em 2em;
      }
#content img.icon {
    height : 120px;
        width :120px;
    padding : 0;
    border : 0 solid #333;
    float : right;
      }
#content img.poems {
    height : 1200px;
    padding : 0;
    border : 0 solid #333;
    float : right;
      }
#footermainPan {
    height : 10%;
    color : #2f5958;
    margin : 0 auto;
    clear : both;
    padding : 6px 0 0;
      }
#playlist tbody tr.even td {
      background-color : #00cc66;
}
#playlist tbody tr.odd  td {
      background-color: #000;
    }
#footerPan {
    width : 100%;
    position : relative;
    margin : 0 auto;
      }
#footerPan ul {
    width :50%;
    height : 0px;
    position : relative;
    margin : 0 auto;
    color : #e0f6f0; 
    text-shadow : 2px 2px 7px #111;  
    text-align : left;
    border : none; 
    font-size : 1.5em; 
    font-weight : bold;
    list-style-type: none;
      }
#footerPan li {
    float: left;
}
#footerPan ul li a {
    padding : 0 10px 0;
    color : #fff;
    background : #184470;
    text-decoration : none;
    font-size : 13px;
}
#footerPan ul li a:hover {
        text-decoration : underline;
}
#footerPan p.copyright {
    width : 250px;
    margin : 10px 0 0 2px;
    position : relative;
    left : 40%;
    color : #fff;
}
```

I am not a regular html/css writer, and I have tried to make the code minimal.
kindly help.

Comment: try to Remove position:absolute; from #galnavigation.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya,

Thanks, that solved the first problem. but href is still beside the img src

Comment: You can give style='  float: left;' to the all anchor tag (<a href="https://picasaweb.google.c...) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the folllowing Js fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/D5sjR/
```

html

```
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
    <h1>
      My Site
    </h1>
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="gal_content">
    <!--<p>-->
    <!--<img src="images/gallery.jpg" alt="MyPic">-->
    <!--</p>-->
    <h2>
      My Gallery 
    </h2>
    Here is some collection of pictures I have taken during several trips. These galleries are hosted in Picasa and Flickr web album.
    <div id="galnavigation">
      <table style="width:94px;margin:0.5em 0 0em 0;" border="0px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
          <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/bnrj.rudra/Garchumuk?feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"> <font style="color:#fff;font-size:.75em; text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Garchumuk</i></font>
<br>
<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7eOvmJb2ASM/R4D-sw0h7YE/AAAAAAAABqw/mR4XSrT2VNM/s160-c/Garchumuk.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 0px;" alt="garchumuk"></a>

        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
          <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/bnrj.rudra/FaltaTrip?feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"><font style="color:#fff; font-size:.75em;text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Falta</i></font>
<br>
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3zQd1oQRUA0/TRgv6Z4AJ8E/AAAAAAAAD-s/Uq2lqhTw_Zo/s160-c/FaltaTrip.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 0px;" alt="falta"></a>
        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/106471678921553351367/TakiTrip?authuser=0&feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"><font style="color:#fff;font-size:.75em; text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Taki Trip</i></font>
<br>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EKTODai7XAs/SXtHhvE6v9E/AAAAAAAAEz8/PCCXLZKBLM4/s160-c/TakiTrip.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 4px;"></a>
        </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footermainPan">
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font : 100% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color : #0a8bf8;
    background : #184470;
    margin : 0;
      }
h1 {

    height : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
      }
.accessaid2, h1 {

    height : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
      }
.accessaid, h1 {

    height : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
      }
#header {
    background : #184470 url(images/banner2.png) no-repeat;
    height : 60px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    border-left : 214px solid #184470;
      }
#navigation {

    top : 60px;
    left : 1%;
    width : 15%;
    color : #e4ecef;
    font-size : 110%;
      }
#navigation ul {
    margin : 0 0 2em 0;
    padding : 0;
    list-style : none;
    color : #e4ecef;
      }
#navigation ul a {
    color : white;
    text-decoration : none;
    display : block;
    background : #4674b2;
    padding : 0 0.5em;
    margin : 0 2em 1px 1em;
    color : #e4ecef;
    box-shadow :0 10px 10px #000;
      }
#navigation a:visited {
    color : #e4ecef;
      }
#navigation a:hover {
    background : #5096f0;
      }
#content {
        background : #e4ecef;
        padding : 0.0em 2.5em;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        --moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        width : 62%;
        float : right;
        margin-right : 17%;
        margin-left : 30%;
        border : 0px;
        background : #e0e9f8;
      }
#gal_content {
        background : #e4ecef;
        padding : 0.0em 2.5em;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        --moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        width : 62%;
        float : right;
        margin-right : 17%;
        margin-left : 30%;
        border : 0px;
        /*background : #e0e9f8;*/
      }
#galnavigation {

    top : 0px;
    left : 23%;
    width : 17%;
    color : #000;
    font-size : 100%;
      }
#galnavigation a:hover {
    background : #5096f0;
      }
#galnavigation ul {
    margin : 100% 0 1em 0;
    padding : 0;
    list-style : none;
    color : #000;
      }
#galnavigation ul a {
    color : white;
    text-decoration : none;
    display : block;
    background : #4674b2;
    padding : 0 0.5em;
    margin : 0 1em 1px 1em;
    color : #e4ecef;
    box-shadow : 0 10px 10px #000;
      }

h2 {
        font-size : 200%;
        color : #184470;
      }
h3 {
        font-size : 125%;
        color : #184470;
      }
#container {
/*position : relative;
width : 100%;
border : solid #036;
border-width : 0 0px;
margin : auto;*/
}
#content img {
        height : 200px;
        padding : 0;
        border : 0 solid #333;
        float : right;
        margin : .5em 0em 2em 2em;
      }
#content img.icon {
    height : 120px;
        width :120px;
    padding : 0;
    border : 0 solid #333;
    float : right;
      }
#content img.poems {
    height : 1200px;
    padding : 0;
    border : 0 solid #333;
    float : right;
      }
#footermainPan {
    height : 10%;
    color : #2f5958;
    margin : 0 auto;
    clear : both;
    padding : 6px 0 0;
      }
#playlist tbody tr.even td {
      background-color : #00cc66;
}
#playlist tbody tr.odd  td {
      background-color: #000;
    }
#footerPan {
    width : 100%;
    position : relative;
    margin : 0 auto;
      }
#footerPan ul {
    width :50%;
    height : 0px;
    position : relative;
    margin : 0 auto;
    color : #e0f6f0; 
    text-shadow : 2px 2px 7px #111;  
    text-align : left;
    border : none; 
    font-size : 1.5em; 
    font-weight : bold;
    list-style-type: none;
      }
#footerPan li {
    float: left;
}
#footerPan ul li a {
    padding : 0 10px 0;
    color : #fff;
    background : #184470;
    text-decoration : none;
    font-size : 13px;
}
#footerPan ul li a:hover {
        text-decoration : underline;
}
#footerPan p.copyright {
    width : 250px;
    margin : 10px 0 0 2px;
    position : relative;
    left : 40%;
    color : #fff;
}
```

I hope this is the way you want

Answer (score 2):

I had to build it from zero because there is not only many css styling, but also styling in the html itself. Here is what i did.

Firstly, replace the table information concerning your gallery. I recommend to use list type for it.

```
<h2>
  My Gallery 
</h2>
<p id="gallery_expl">Here is some collection of pictures I have taken during several trips. These galleries are hosted in Picasa and Flickr web album.</p>
<div id="galnavigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/bnrj.rudra/Garchumuk?feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"> <font style="color:#fff;font-size:.75em; text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  margin-left: 25px; border:none;"><i>Garchumuk</i></font><br /><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7eOvmJb2ASM/R4D-sw0h7YE/AAAAAAAABqw/mR4XSrT2VNM/s160-c/Garchumuk.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 0px;" alt="garchumuk"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/bnrj.rudra/FaltaTrip?feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"><font style="color:#fff; font-size:.75em;text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Falta</i></font><br /><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3zQd1oQRUA0/TRgv6Z4AJ8E/AAAAAAAAD-s/Uq2lqhTw_Zo/s160-c/FaltaTrip.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 0px;" alt="falta"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://picasaweb.google.com/106471678921553351367/TakiTrip?authuser=0&feat=embedwebsite" target="_blank"><font style="color:#fff;font-size:.75em; text-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #111;  text-align:center; border:none;"><i>Taki Trip</i></font><br /><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EKTODai7XAs/SXtHhvE6v9E/AAAAAAAAEz8/PCCXLZKBLM4/s160-c/TakiTrip.jpg" width="94" height="94" style="margin:1px 0 0 4px;"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

then with css

```
body {
    font : 100% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color : #0a8bf8;
    background : #184470;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
div#header h1 {
text-align: center;
}
/* remove bullets and indent of list */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
/* ensure that multiple h1 navigations are left of each other */
div#container li a {
    color : white;
    text-decoration : none;
    display : block;
    background : #4674b2;
    padding : 0 0.5em;
    margin : 0 2em 1px 1em;
    color : #e4ecef;
    box-shadow :0 10px 10px #000;
}

#gal_content {
    background : #e4ecef;
    /*padding : 0.0em 2.5em; */
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    --moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width : 98%;
    /*float : right;
    /*margin-right : 17%;
    /*margin-left : 30%;*/
    border : 0px;
    /*background : #e0e9f8;*/
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}

div#gal_content h2 {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

p#gallery_expl {
text-align: center;
}
div#galnavigation {
  clear: both;
  width: 50em;
 margin-left: 2.5em;
}
div#galnavigation li {
float:left;
    width: 15em;
}
div#galnavigation li * {
    text-align: center;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
div#galnavigation li a {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

The result is as [image: shown here]

PS : oh upload took long and just noticed the above reply (i also didn't got a notification... oh well...)